# 6-6 pane with 6-3-3 underneath

Tags: html, css

I need it to be like this:

http://qs.lc/tdcw9

But it currently looks like this:

http://qs.lc/z252x

They are aligned. Does anyone know how I get a 3-3 underneath "jouw nieuws" without it getting aligned, like on the first screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

That would work if you choose to go for a 2 column layout, with the second column having a full width 1 column first row, followed by a two column second row.

Here is a rough example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="col-md-12">
                Lorem ipsum col 1-1 text
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
                Lorem ipsum col 1-2 text
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="col-md-12">
                Lorem ipsum col 2 text
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">
                Sub col 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                 Sub col 2
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sygfczeq/1/

This example uses bootstrap, but should work for any grid system.